# Midpoint Riemann Sum Code

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am trying to write a code in order to find the Riemann sum for the midpoint but can't seem to get the correct answer. I double checked what the answer should be but I haven't been able to find what's wrong with the code. My test code is

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]
Mid[f, 0, pi/2, 5]

Mid[f_, a_, b_, n_] := Sum[f[2 a + 2 i] (b - a)/n + (b - a)/n, {i, 0, n - 1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of mid-point rule looks wrong. Here is an implementation the I know works and will be faster than one using `Sum`.

```
area[f_, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, n_Integer?Positive] := 
  With[{dx = (b - a)/n},
    (f[a] + f[a + dx/2] + f[b - dx/2] + f[b]) dx/4 +
      Plus @@ MovingAverage[f /@ Range[a + dx/2, b - dx/2, dx], 2] dx]
```

#### Tests

```
f[x_] := x Sin[x]
area[f, 0, π/2, 5] // N
```

> `1.00763`

```
area[Sin, 0, π/2, 100] // N
```

> `1.00002`

```
NIntegrate[f[x], {x, 0, π/2}]
```

> `1.`